# EMV Tag 91 Issuer Authentication Data - How to Determine Format of Tag in Response

Tags: smartcard, payment-processing, emv

If present, EMV Tag 91 Issuer Authentication Data can have several different formats when returned in a transaction response. From my (limited) understanding, this may be determined by the card brand.

For example

- MasterCard Tag 91 includes Card Status Update as part of Tag 91 data
- Visa Tag 91 includes the Authorization Response Code as the last two bytes of Tag 91 data.

I need to solve a problem where Tag 8A Authorization Response Data is not returned as part of the EMV tag data in the case of a non approval response. The payment platform has advised to take the last 2 bytes of tag 91 and assign it to tag 8A, but tag 91 does not always contain the Authorization Response Code Value and Tag 8A is not always returned in some cases or brands.

I'd like to implement a more robust fix where we validate the format of tag 91 instead of just saying If Visa... do this... If Discover.... do that.

Any suggestions on how tag 91 is structured such as a reference to EMV Book documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 8):

I investigated this problem in past and here are the results.

In case tag `0x8A` is unknown it can be taken from tag `0x91`, but only for some Card Brands/profiles.

In general, if the length of `0x91` is 10 bytes (20 hex chars), the tag value can split to:

- 8 bytes **ARPC**;
- 2 bytes **Authorization Response Code** (ARC, i.e. tag `0x8A`) or **Card Status Update** (**CSU**) or **ARPC Response Code**;

**The tag `0x8A` presented inside tag `0x91` in next card profiles:**

- Amex (ref. AEIPS, "Issuer Authentication");
- JCB (ref. JCB ICC Specification, "EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE Command");
- MasterCard (only for M/Chip Lite v2.1);
- Visa (ref. VIS, "Online Request and Response Data");
- UnionPay (ref. UICC, "Online processing");

**IT IS NOT a case to extract `0x8A` value from tag `0x91` for next card profiles:**

- Diners/Discover (ref. D-PAS, "ISSUER AUTHENTICATION"), inside tag `0x91` placed Card Status Update (CSU);
- MasterCard (ref. M/Chip version <> 2.1), tag `0x91` with different length or inside tag `0x91` placed ARPC Response Code. It is not ARC;
- CCD-complaint EMV cards (ref. EMV), used different length and format of tag `0x91`;

Extraction of tag `0x8A` value from tag `0x91` may work only as temporary solution. You may see not all card profiles allow it.
In fact it needs to be returned in clear form Acquirer in the reply message.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying how this is to be handled.

Comment: thank you for your guidance. Can I ask for additional help and ask for the specific file names of the brand documents referenced above? I have access to my company's document repository but nothing is organized well and documents are not really stored in the expected places so finding all of these documents is not proving fruitful.  Thank you!

Comment: All references in my answer to the Card brands specifications: AEIPS, D-PAS, M/CHIP, VIS, UICC. Specification filenames could be different, but they strictly point to Brand Card profiles with supported APDU commands and used Tags.